# Why does the shape property in material ui only affect the corners from buttons but NOT checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Why does the shape property only affect the corner radius from a button and not change the checkbox as well?

I need one property to say make everything square except radio buttons HAHA :D

```
const theme = createTheme({
      shape: {
        borderRadius: 0,
      },
}); 

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Button>Import</Button>
        <Checkbox></Checkbox>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `checkbox` component does not use the `shape` property, but instead uses its own `icon` and `checkedIcon` props to render the checkbox appearance.

If you want to change the checkbox appearance, you can use the `icon` and `checkedIcon` props to provide custom icons for the `unchecked` and `checked` states.

For example:

```
<Checkbox
  label="CheckCircleIcon"
  icon={<CustomUncheckedIcon />}
  checkedIcon={<CustomCheckedIcon />}
/>
```

To learn more, please see [MUI Checkbox API Doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/checkbox/#prop-checkedIcon).